# Soap Request in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, xml, visual-studio, soap

I've got a soap request I've written in http & javascript but I cannot seem to convert it into C# correctly.

Original: (Works)

```html
<button onclick="doStuff()" type="submit">Send</button>

<textarea name="REQUEST_DATA" cols=120 rows=17 >
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<createModifyRequest>
<username>josephs</username>
<lookupIds>
<lookupIds>4225</lookupIds><!--firepass-->
</lookupIds>
</createModifyRequest>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
</textarea>

<script language="javascript"> 

function doStuff() {

var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");

xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://tpdev-itreq.transpower.co.nz:7777/usr/services/CreateModifyRequest", false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "createModifyRequest");

var userpass = "josephs" + ":" + "pass";
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + (userpass));

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
xmlhttp.send(REQUEST_DATA.value);

}
```

Converted in C# (Does not work)

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string soap =@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" 
      xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" 
   xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
  <soap:Body>
    <createModifyRequest>
        <username>josephs</username>
        <lookupIds>
            <lookupIds>4225</lookupIds>
            <!--firepass-->
       </lookupIds>
    </createModifyRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>";

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://tpdev-itreq.transpower.co.nz:7777/usr/services/CreateModifyRequest");
    req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"createModifyRequest\"");

    var userpass = "josephs" + ":" + "pass";

    req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + (userpass));
    // req.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml");

    req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    req.Accept = "text/xml";
    req.Method = "POST";

    using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
        {
            stmw.Write(soap);
        }
    }

    WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();

    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    // TODO: Do whatever you need with the response
}
```

At the moment when I run the C# code I get an internal 500 server error, so what have I done wrong?

Comment: Does it have any stacktrace?

Comment: Have you checked that the XML string is valid? use a tool to check http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.UafOWEqmXwk

Comment: yes it is, the status is: System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError

Comment: i think im missing something in my C# code, because the version i wrote in java works fine

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler and compare the working and non-working requests. You can also access the server logs to see a useful error.

Comment: I have `The remote name could not be resolved: 'tpdev-itreq.transpower.co.nz'` error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce your problem. Currently i am not able to create your request but i have generated local request with your data. 
One thing I came to know is if I **remove double quotes(") around the utf-8** and it worked fine.
Just pass **charset=utf-8** instead of **charset=\"utf-8\""**

I am not sure it will work for you or not.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you can't just use Visual Studio's built in support for SOAP web services?

You can add a [service reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) or a [web reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx) (depending on whch framework version you are targeting).

Then you can just use the proxy class that VS creates for you.

There's no advantage to writing all of the HTTP code yourself.  Actually, there's a big disadvantage, in that you are aren't getting proper data types from the WSDL of your SOAP service.